# How can I change the font size of my navbar items

Tags: html, css

I am making a navigation bar for my website and I am relatively new to HTML, I am trying to set the font size of the nav links to 17px but it is not working. When I try it the font size just stays the same.

I tried changing the font in the .nav tag, like this:

```
<div class="navbar">
        <div class="nav-bg">
            <!-- nav background container -->
        </div>
        <h1 class="title-text"><span class="text-gradient" >Cosmic</span> Studios</h1>
        <div class="nav">
            <h1 class="home">Home</h1>
            <h1 class="proxies">Proxies</h1>
            <h1 class="courses">Courses</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
```

```
.nav {
    display: flex;
    gap: 25px;
    color: var(--text-color);
    font-size: 17px;
    font-family: 'Manrope';
    font-style: normal;
}
```

I also tried referencing each individual element, i.e: .home, .proxies. courses etc. but that messed with some other elements, what should I do

Comment: make sure your `h1` style isn't overriding your css somewhere else. Best way to check this is right click on the text in your browser and click `inspect element`. Your browser should show you which css style is taking priority

Answer (score 1):

```
.nav h1{ 
  font-size: 17px
}
```

or

```
.nav.home, .nav.proxies, .nav.courses {
  font-size: 17px
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you're facing this issue.
I tried your code and it's changing the size to 17px.
[image]

Try refreshing the page after you make some changes or you can use Chrome Developer tool.
(Ctr+Shift+I)
Under the element and styles tab you can check if your css is getting suppressed by higher priority css.
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_specificity.asp check out this link for css specificity

Answer (score 0):

HTML :

```html
<div class="navbar">
      <div class="nav-bg">
        <!-- nav background container -->
      </div>
      <h1 class="title-text"><span class="text-gradient">Cosmic</span> Studios</h1>
      <div class="nav">
        <h1 class="home">Home</h1>
        <h1 class="proxies">Proxies</h1>
        <h1 class="courses">Courses</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
  display: flex;
  gap: 25px;
  color: var(--text-color);
  font-size: 17px;
  font-family: "Manrope";
  font-style: normal;
}
```

**Note** : It's not a good practice to use `<h1></h1>` multiple times and `<h1></h1>` not as nav elements.

Answer (score 0):

you should try to use first-child and nth-child in your css code

```
<div class="navbar">
    <div class="nav-bg">
    <!-- nav background container -->
</div>
<h1 class="title-text"><span class="text-gradient" >Cosmic</span> Studios</h1>
<div class="nav">
    <h1 class="home">Home</h1>
    <h1 class="proxies">Proxies</h1>
    <h1 class="courses">Courses</h1>
</div>`enter code here`
```

comma in css syntax tells that we will target elements together with the same css command

```
.nav {
    display: flex;
    gap: 25px;
    color: #000000;
    font-family: 'Manrope';
    font-style: normal;
}
.nav:first-child, .nav:nth-child(2), .nav:last-child{
    font-size: 17px;
}
```

or tag all h1 elements inside the nav class

```
.nav h1{
    font-size: 17px;
```